# OpenPop.net get actual message text

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, openpop

I am using OpenPop.net to try and parse our links from all the emails that are in a given inbox. I found this method to get all the message:

```
    public static List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> FetchAllMessages(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
    {
        // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
        using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            // Connect to the server
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

            // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
            client.Authenticate(username, password);

            // Get the number of messages in the inbox
            int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

            // We want to download all messages
            List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);

            // Messages are numbered in the interval: [1, messageCount]
            // Ergo: message numbers are 1-based.
            // Most servers give the latest message the highest number
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));                    
            }

            client.Disconnect();

            // Now return the fetched messages
            return allMessages;
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to loop through each message but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it, I have this so far for my button:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allaEmail = FetchAllMessages("pop3.live.com", 995, true, "xxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxx");

        var message = string.Join(",", allaEmail);
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

How would i loop through each entry in allaEmail so that i can display it in a MessageBox?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I can see that you use the [fetchAllEmail example](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleFetchAllMessages.php) from the OpenPop homepage. A similar example [showing how to get body text](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSpecificParts.php) is also on the homepage.

You might also want to look at how emails are actually structured. A [email introduction](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/emailIntroduction.php) exists for just this purpose.

Having that said, I would do something similar to the code below.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allaEmail = FetchAllMessages(...);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(OpenPop.Mime.Message message in allaEmail)
    {
         OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainText = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
         if(plainText != null)
         {
             // We found some plaintext!
             builder.Append(plainText.GetBodyAsText());
         } else
         {
             // Might include a part holding html instead
             OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart html = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();
             if(html != null)
             {
                 // We found some html!
                 builder.Append(html.GetBodyAsText());
             }
         }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
}
```

I hope this can help you on the way. Notice that there is also [online documentation](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.html) for OpenPop.

Comment: WOW thank you foens! That was exactly what i was after! :) Checkbox comming

Comment: html.GetBodyAsText() gives an exception says the objectreference not set to an instance. but i get the value using FindFirstPlainTextVersion() and then plainText.GetBodyAsText() any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
string Body = msgList[0].MessagePart.MessageParts[0].GetBodyAsText();
            foreach( string d in Body.Split('\n')){
                Console.WriteLine(d);                    
            }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since this was shorter, I tried your option, but it did not work.  Gave me array conversion complaints.  @foens solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers in this question are incomplete and icorrect, mainly because they never use `FindAllTextVersions` method which is crucial.

Here is the complete method to get the actual body text content:

```
private static string GetMessageBodyAsText(Message message)
{
    try
    {
        List<MessagePart> list = message.FindAllTextVersions();

        // First let's try getting the plain text part:
        foreach (MessagePart part in list)
        {
            if (part != null)
            {
                return part.GetBodyAsText();
            }
        }

        // Now let's try getting the HTML part
        MessagePart html = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();
        if (html != null)
        {
            return html.GetBodyAsText();
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Handle your exception here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the entire HTML message is in one part and plain text is in many parts?